# Evaluate logical expression in postfix/rpn form

Tags: javascript, logic, postfix-notation, truthtable

I have some variables

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = true;
```

and propositional logic expression (in infix=`a | b & c`) as postfix

```
a b | c &
```

I want to evaluate the truth value.

I have found http://eddmann.com/posts/small-rpn-implementation-in-javascript/ which does it for arithmetic.

How can I do the same for just logical symbols?

Comment: Since that code uses `eval()`, you need to change `&` and `|` to `&&` and `||`, since those are Javascript's logical operators. Then it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't `t == +t ? t ...` be changed to something that checks if `t` a varable name and if it's defined?

Comment: Change that to `typeof t == 'boolean'`.